# req.body is saying undefined while running on postman

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, express, req

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql=require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var con=mysql.createConnection({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"",
    database:"nodedb"
});

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.post('/reg', function (req, res) {     
    var name=req.body.user_name;
    console.log(name);

    con.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?", [req.body.email],
    function(err,result){       
            if(result.length > 0){
            console.log('mail already exist');
            res.json('mail already exist');

            }
        else{
  con.query("INSERT INTO users (`name`,`email`,`contact`,`password`) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ",  [req.body.user_name,req.body.email,req.body.contact_no, req.body.user_password],
    function(err1,result1){
        if(err1){

        console.log('failed');  
        res.json(err1);
        }
        else{
            console.log('1 recoed inserted');   
            res.json(result1);

        }

 })
        }
})
}
```

> req.body.user_name print undefined in console and null on postman. It
>   is working on web page but not on postman. What should i do now. I looked in many websites but i didn't get answer.

Comment: have you tried logging request, console.log(req,body); ?

Comment: i did console(req.body) it's printing blank json {}.

Answer (score 4):

You need to select the correct **header content type**: x-www-form-urlencoded

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: My raputation is less than 15, so it won't show. I guess you know that.

Comment: Thanks t3__rry :)

Answer (score 3):

In the body of postman, make sure you are using raw and make the Application type to Application/json, then you can mention

```
{
  "user_name": "Your_name"    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You might not have initialized the middleware for using the body parser. Here's how you can do it:

Put `app.use(express.json());` in the entry point of your project.